# How to show a checked subcategory of a post in loop WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some subcategories releted a category "news".

- News
- --news-topic-1
- --news-topic-2
- --news-topic-3

I have a loop of posts where all posts are from the news category, but I want to display only the subcategory marked in the registered post.

- Post 1
- -- news-topic-1
- Post 2
- -- news-topic-2

my current loop displays all news related subcategories or just the first subcategory and not just the one marked in the post register
[post marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZLBT.png)

Display:
[how it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N50nX.png)

the post displays the first subcategory it finds or all related to news

I would like it to display only the marked subcategory

My loop:

```
$args = array( 
            'posts_per_page' => 8,
            'category_name' => 'news',
        );
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
 while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
<p class="cat_list_pots__content__subcat">
                            <?php
$subcategories = get_categories(get_the_ID());
var_dump($subcategories);
$subCatArry = [];
foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory)
{
    $subcategorySLUG = strtolower($subcategory->slug);
    array_push($subCatArry, $subcategory->name);
}
echo $subCatArry[count($subCatArry) - 1];

?>
                        </p>
 <?php
endwhile; ?>
<?php
else:
    echo "<p>" . $message . "</p>";
endif;
?>

enter code here
enter code here
```

Comment: You are using the wrong function, `get_categories` will get you the terms inside a taxonomy, this has not relation to any specific post. You need to use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/

Comment: With your suggestion I was able to come up with a solution. Thank you very much.